# I am trying to insert hyperlink to another website in pdf

Tags: c#, aspose.pdf

In FormField "HH" i am trying to make text as link, but it is readed only as string text, it is not clickable.
I use Aspose.Pdf v.11.6.0.

```cs
var doc = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(pdfFileStream);

var pdfForm = new Aspose.Pdf.Facades.Form(doc);
pdfForm.FillField("Name", model.Name.ToUpper());
pdfForm.FillField("ISOS", model.NumberISOS.ToUpper());
pdfForm.FillField("Info", dateInfo);

pdfForm.FillField("HH", "http://www.somewebsite.com");
```

I use this code:

```
 Page page = (Page)doc.Pages[1];
 var text = new TextFragment("index");
 text.Position = new Position(200, 300);
 Aspose.Pdf.WebHyperlink link = new 
 WebHyperlink("www.google.com");
 text.Hyperlink = link;
 page.Paragraphs.Add(text);
```

but new Position(200, 300); values not responding.

Comment: Are you looking at the documentation they have tried it? https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/Add+and+Get+Hyperlink

Comment: As for `Aspose.Pdf.Facades.Form` don't see any method for Hyperlink
[Documentation](https://apireference.aspose.com/net/pdf/aspose.pdf.facades/form)

Comment: I use code from documentation https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/Add+and+Get+Hyperlink "Add Hyperlink in a PDF File" ,
and i got the link in my pdf, but i can not understand how can i set position of the link. 
printscr: https://ibb.co/Zd1pYj2

Comment: I posted same question at  the official help forum for aspose:
https://forum.aspose.com/t/hyperlink-in-a-specific-position-inside-document-pdf/31372/3

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, because position does not work, i move the link with margins. This worked for me.

```
Page page = (Page)doc.Pages[1];
var text = new TextFragment("LINK");
text.Position = new Position(300, 300);
Aspose.Pdf.WebHyperlink link = new WebHyperlink("www.google.com");
text.Hyperlink = link;
text.Margin.Left = -48;
text.Margin.Top = 687;
text.Margin.Bottom = -150;
text.TextState.Underline = true;
text.TextState.FontSize = 11;

text.TextState.ForegroundColor = Aspose.Pdf.Color.DeepSkyBlue;
text.TextState.BackgroundColor = Aspose.Pdf.Color.White;
page.Paragraphs.Add(text);
```

Comment: It is good to know that you managed to resolve your issue. In case you face any issue, please feel free to let us know via Aspose.PDF Forums (https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf). We will be more than happy to assist you accordingly. This is Asad Ali and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.